# How to query on attribute of ToManyField with django-tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie, django-queryset

**Edit: This approach does work, I had a typo. Thanks @eran for pointing it out, fixed below.**

In console I can do this:

```
Performance.objects.filter(ticket_blocks__price__gt=200)
```

And get performances that have ticket blocks with price greater than $200. But this:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/performance/?ticket_blocks__price__gt=200
```

Gives me `KeyError: u'price'`. What am I doing wrong?

**models.py**

```
class TicketBlock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

class Performance(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    sold_out = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # All performance have at least one ticket block
    ticket_blocks = models.ManyToManyField('TicketBlock')
```

**api.py**

```
class TicketBlockResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = TicketBlock.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        resource_name = 'ticket-block'
        filtering = {
            'price': ALL
        }

class PerformanceResource(ModelResource):
    ticket_blocks = fields.ToManyField(TicketBlockResource, 'ticket_blocks', blank=True, null=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Performance.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        resource_name = 'performance'
        filtering = {
            'ticket_blocks': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT should work, I think you just have confusion in the definitions and used the wrong model `VenueType` instead of `TicketBlock`

Change the line:

```
queryset = VenueType.objects.all()
```

to:

```
TicketBlock.objects.all()
```

and I think it will fix your problem.